# Translate these statements into English

Tags: logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Translate the following statements into English, where $C(x)$ means '$x$ is a comedian', $F(x)$ means '$x$ is funny' and the domain consists of all people:

a) ∀x(C(x) → F(x)) 
b) ∀x(C(x) ∧ F(x)) 
c) ∃x(C(x) → F(x)) 
d) ∃x(C(x) ∧ F(x))

this my Sol :
a- for all people If comedians , then are funny.
b- Every people are comedians and funny.
c- some person If a comedian , then is funny.
d- some person comedian is funny.

Correct ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Your (c) is wrong. The formula in the question is also true if there exists a non-comedian (funny or not).

Comment: $C(x)\nrightarrow F(x)$...

Comment: thank you , now there aren't wrong in my solution ?

Comment: @Bsha Your solutions are fine! However, since our objective is to translate the formal expressions above to (proper) English language, I think it would be nicer to take off the mathematical jargon (all, some etc.) and express them more naturally in ordinary language. Barry Cipra pointed it out too bellow in a good reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is to translate the symbolic formulas into English sentences that a non-mathematician can easily understand, here are my recommendations:

> a) All comedians are funny.
>
> b) Everyone is a funny comedian.
>
> c) *To be discussed below.*
>
> d) There is at least one comedian who is actually funny.

(Note the inclusion of the word "actually." It doesn't affect the logic of the claim, it just calls attention to the possibility that a comedian might not be funny.  Similarly, the use of "at least one" instead of just "a" makes clear that you're not trying to say there's *only* one funny comedian.)

The formula c) warrants a little extra discussion.  It can be translated directly into this:

> c) There's someone who, if they are a comedian, then they are funny.

But I don't think most people would immediately grasp that this statement is satisfied by the existence of a single non-comedian.  To phrase it in a way that makes sense, I think you have to go with something like this:

> c) If everyone is a comedian, then somebody must be funny.

Symbolically this says $(\forall x C(x))\rightarrow (\exists xF(x))$ instead of $\exists x(C(x)\rightarrow F(x))$, but these two formulations are tautologically equivalent.  Translating from one "language" to another sometimes calls for reformulation, if clarity of expression is the goal.

Answer (score 2):

A: For all people, if they are a comedian, then they are funny. B: For all people, they are comedians and they are funny. C: There exist a person such that if they are a comedian, they are funny. D: there exist a person who is funny and also a comedian.

Answer (score 2):

A: All comedians are funny
B: All people are funny comedians 
C: There exist a comedian that is funny
D: A person is a funny comedian.

Answer (score 2):

Every comedian is funny.

Everyone is a funny comedian.

There is a person who is either not a comedian or a funny comedian.

There is a funny comedian.

Comment: I don't see a negation sign for (c)

Comment: @KrzysztofMyśliwiec: That's funny.